# How to connect to a PSQL database on the same network but running on a different computer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried a lot of things, my understanding so far is to have the psql server (computer1) listen to the other computer (computer2) that is going to connect to it. I opened my pg_hba config file:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.5/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

So far it looks like it is listening to all servers running on local network.

When I try to connect from computer2 using CMD

```
psql -h 127.0.0.5 -U postgres;
```

I get prompted to enter my password, but the database I connect to is the database running on computer2, not the one running on computer1

What can I do here? Thank you for reading so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. `psql` is the name of the Postgres client. When referring to the server use Postgres or Postgresql.
2. pg_hba.conf is for client authentication not setting up the address the server is listening on.
3. The contents of pg_hba.conf that you show indicate the server will only accept clients connecting from the same machine.
4. The setting you are looking for is in postgresql.conf as [listen_addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS)
5. Read this [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for more information on how to set it up.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. I gathered more info and I tried to test out a solution. I found the IPv4 address for computer1 (192.168.1.200) and the one for computer2 (192.168.1.30). I added computer2 IPv4 address to my pg_hba config file host    all             all             192.168.1.30/0               md5 and I tried to connect from pgadmin on computer2 by adding computer1 IPv4 address on create server button. But I'm still unable to connect. what can I do here?

Comment: @momomo After doing those things, what error message did you get?

Comment: You didn't read the entire answer. Look at 4) again.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did read 4, and I checked 4 before even posting this question. My listen addresses are configured like this:  listen_addresses = '*'    on default. I don't know what else am I missing

Comment: @jjanes I get connection timed out. It's like I'm missing something

Comment: Is there a firewall set up on computer 1?